# Transfer function with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I trying to calculate the step and impulse response for a transfer function `G=1/s^2`. I am using the Matlab command `tf` and here is the code

```
num = [1 ]; 
den = [1 0 0]; 
G = tf(num,den);
step(G);
impulse(G);
```

My problem is that they don't have the same y- and x-axis scale, Matlab seems to give them random numbers. How do I change so that the y-axis begins from 0 to 100, and the same for the x-axis, for both the step and impulse?

Answer (score 1):

```
step(G,100);   % sets the final time
axis([0 100 0 100]); % sets the x-axis and y-axis limits for the current axes
figure
impulse(G,100);
axis([0 100 0 100]);
```

Comment: @Planet_hunter [Accepts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) are even better than thanks. :)